# using only one <div> tag or a single <header> tag to cycle through background images using fadeIn()

Tags: jquery

Does anyone have a solution only using one  tag or a single  tag? This solutions uses 2 div tags:

`<div id="background1"></div> <div id="background2"></div>.`

[Cycle through background images using fadeIn()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691906/cycle-through-background-images-using-fadein/43416107#43416107)

Comment: Halo. Does @Praxis or anyone have a solution which uses only a single <div> tag or a single <header> tag? Praxis solution uses 2 div tags: <div id="background1"></div> <div id="background2"></div>. Praxis solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691906/cycle-through-background-images-using-fadein/43416107#43416107. Peter: kindly leave question as is. thanks

Comment: @peter kindly don't edit my question again please. solutions are welcome. thanks/

Comment: Your post was edited by threxx (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43416344/revisions)) in order to make your question easier to understand, which will make it more likely to be answered and more likely to be useful to other people afterwards.

Comment: the point is to make it easier to understand. If your aim actually does achieve this, and additionally makes it more likely to be answered and more likely to be useful to other people afterwards. thanks :-)

Comment: sorry Peter.thank you Peter and Threxx. Thank you any and all who provide a timely detailed solution. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout Back Stretch. Its a nifty library that maybe an alternative to what you're writing. http://www.jquery-backstretch.com/

Comment: thanks Tyharo. I'd seen that before; it might be a last resort. I wanted to work on the mentioned solution.

Comment: Halo. Hope this helps:

Below is the stripped down version of the Page' source code I'm working on. I want the <HEADER> BACKGROUND images to be automatically swapped with a  smooth FADE transition (FadeIn +/- Fadeout). What's available so far are [foreground] IMAGES, not BACKGROUND images attached/passed into the <BODY>/<DIV>/<IMG> tags. As a result, they either cover the page text (which only become visible midway during transition when opacity is less than 1). I need the I appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

Comment: PAGE SOURCE CODE
==================

<html>
<head>
<!--//
Meta tags
//-->

<!--//
Style sheets & Font links
//-->

<!--//
General Scripts(JavaScript, JQuery)
//-->

</head>
 <body oncontextmenu = "return false;" ondrag = "return false;">
 
 <div id="page">
 <nav class="navigationClass" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-left">

Comment: <a 

href="index.htm"><img src="img/logo.png" width="120" height="25" 

border="0"> </a></div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 text-right 

menu-1">
     <ul>
      <li 

class="active"><a href="index.htm">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
       <a 

href="#">COMPANY</a>
       <ul 

class="dropdown">
        

<li><a href="company.htm">Company information</a></li>
        

<li><a href="company.htm#Mgt">Senior Management</a></li>
        

<li><a href="partners.htm">Partners</a></li>
       

</ul>
    </li>

Comment: <li 

class="has-dropdown">
       <a 

href="#">SERVICES</a>
       <ul 

class="dropdown">
        

<li><a href="services.htm">Overview</a></li>
                                <li><a href="services/1.htm">abc-xyz services[1]</a></li>
        

<li><a href="services/2.htm">abc-xyz services[2]</a></li>
        

<li><a href="services/3.htm">abc-xyz services[3]</a></li>
       

</ul>
      </li>

           <li><a 

href="portfolio.htm">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a 

href="blog.htm">BLOG</a></li>

Comment: <li><a href="contact.htm">CONTACT US</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>

Comment: <header id="headerID" class="coverClass" role="banner" 

style="background-image: url(img/img_1.jpg)">

Comment: <div class="">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-

offset-0 text-left">
                
     <div class="row-mt-

15em">
      <div 

class="col-md-7 mt-text animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInUp">
       

<span class="intro-text-small">ABC XYZ</span>
<h1 class="mb30">abc-xyz etc.</h1>
                            <p><a href="videos/abc-xyz.mp4" class="btn btn-

primary">ABC-XYZ</a></p> 
      </div><div class="col-md-4 

col-md-push-1 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInRight">
        

<br><br><br><br>

Comment: <div class="form-wrap">
<div class="tab">
<ul class="tab-menu">
<li class=""><a href="#" data-tab="login">User login</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-content-inner active" data-content="login">
<form action="#">
<div class="row form-group">
<div class="col-md-12"><label for="loginID">Username or Email</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginID" name="loginID" required autofocus>
</div></div><div class="row form-group">
 <!--FORM & other info--></div>

Comment: <div class="row form-group"><div class="col-md-12" align="right"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login"></div></div></form>

Comment: </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></header>
<footer id="nice-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div class="container">
<div class="copyright">&copy; 2017 ABC-XYZ</div>
</div>
</footer>
</div>
 <!-- jQuery & JavaScript goes below -->
</body>
</html>
===========

Comment: and everyone else. Thank you

Comment: @Peter-hall
I just pasted a stripped down version of the page code. I would appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

Comment: @threxx
I just pasted a stripped down version of the page code here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416344/using-only-one-div-tag-or-a-single-header-tag-to-cycle-through-background-im/43418344#43418344](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416344/using-only-one-div-tag-or-a-single-header-tag-to-cycle-through-background-im/43418344#43418344). I would appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

Comment: @Praxis_Ashelin
I just pasted a stripped down version of the page code here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416344/using-only-one-div-tag-or-a-single-header-tag-to-cycle-through-background-im/43418344#43418344](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416344/using-only-one-div-tag-or-a-single-header-tag-to-cycle-through-background-im/43418344#43418344). I would appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

Comment: @Praxis-Ashelin
I just pasted a stripped down version of the page code here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416344/using-only-one-div-tag-or-a-single-header-tag-to-cycle-through-background-im/43418344#43418344](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416344/using-only-one-div-tag-or-a-single-header-tag-to-cycle-through-background-im/43418344#43418344). I would appreciate your assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Hi:Still haven't had an answer. I'll go with Tyaro's. Thank you.